# Using 'System.Lazy.LazyThreadSafetyMode' with MEF

Tags: thread-safety, mef, lazy-evaluation

I import many parts from different assemblies into my class like this:

```
[ImportMany(typeof(IServiceProvider))]
private IEnumerable<Lazy<IServiceProvider, IDictionary<string, object>>> ServiceProviders
   {
       get;
       set;
   }
```

After parts imported, Service providers are created on demand:

```
private IServiceProvider GetServiceProvider(String name)
{
    foreach (var serviceProvider in ServiceProviders)
    {
        String currentName = (String)serviceProvider.Metadata["Name"];
        if (currentName == name)
            return serviceProvider.Value; // Many threads receive here and try to create new instance.
    }

    return null;
}
```

As I commented in above code, many threads try to get `value` of the `lazy` variable (create new instance of it, if not created yet) at the same time.

`Lazy<T>`has a constructor which allow to create instance (`value`) in a `thread-safe` manner, like this:

```
// Something here...
Dictionary<string, object> metadata = new Dictionary<string,object>();
metadata.Add("Name", "test");
Lazy<IServiceProvider, IDictionary<string, object>> serviceProvider = new Lazy<IServiceProvider, IDictionary<string, object>>(ServiceProviderValueFactory, metadata, System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);
// Now access to 'serviceProvider.Value' creates an instance (if not created yet) in a thread-safe manner.

private IServiceProvider ServiceProviderValueFactory()
{
    // Create and return a new instance of 'IServiceProvider'.
}
```

`MEF` take cares of object creation when importing parts and I want to use the `Lazy` constructor which allows for thread-safe `value` creation but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating your `CompositionContainer`, pass `isThreadSafe=true` to the constructor.

Note that it's not safe to do any recomposition in a thread-safe container, so you shouldn't use catalogs that change, or `CompositionBatch`, or the `AttributedModelServices.ComposeParts()` extension method.

Comment: Actually I need to refresh the `DirectoryCatalog` to add/remove and replace changed plugins from container. Is this against thread safety ?

Comment: @Xaqron Yes, that would be against thread safety.  If this is a server-side application it's probably best to just create a new catalog and container which will be used for all future requests and let the current container be used for the current requests to finish.  If it's a client app you would probably need to pause work on any other threads that might access the container before doing the catalog refresh.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced this is something you can change.  The `Lazy<T, M>` type is initialised through the `ExportServices` internal class, and cannot be overridden.  If you subclassed `ExportProvider` the target `GetExports` or `GetExportsCore` that return `Lazy<T, M>` are not abstract or virtual so cannot be overridden.

In `ExportServices`, it is hard coded as:

```
return new Lazy<T, M>(..., LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly);
```

Comment: +1 for details I didn't know. Although the source is available on `codeplex` I'm not gonna fork my version. New libraries like `MEF` and `Lazy` have problem with parametrized constructors and made me a lot of problem.